# what is a fundamental property of a Python class to be "stable" under multiprocessing?

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing, sage

In SageMath, I've seen at least two cases of the following issue. We have a function that constructs and returns elements from the same class, and it works as expected when it's called sequentially. However, when this function is called in parallel via `multiprocessing` functionality, the returned elements happen to come from different instances of the underlying class.

A recent example is described in SageMath's [issue #37278](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/37278). And another one is [described at ask.sagemath.org](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/63243/).

Not every class fails this way under `multiprocessing`, some remain "stable" no matter whether the elements are constructed sequentially or in parallel. From issue #37278 linked above, SageMath's [Permutations class](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/develop/src/sage/combinat/permutation.py) is stable, while [PermutationGroup class](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/develop/src/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup.py) is not. It seems that those that are unstable miss something is their definition.

> Q: What is the fundamental property of a class that makes it stable under the use of `multiprocessing` ?

Comment: Wow, I just looked at the links you shared to the code of the two classes, and those are complex! It won't be easy to pinpoint the source. Generally, though, it does have to do with shared memory, or the assumption that different instances share the same memory space, which is not true across processes. Figuring out what in PermutationGroup makes assumptions that are invalid across processes will be quite a task!

Comment: @joanis: The other linked example with a custom class may be easier to digest. Just in case, here is a link to a code at Sagecell illustrating the issue: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=etsftp

Comment: Yeah, I read that example as well when I first looked at your question. I'm afraid the developers of the package will have to solve this one, or someone very familiar with it. The code has to be made parallel-processing aware, and that's actually quite hard to do at the best of times, because any kind of shared state or global has to be rethought considering it's no longer actually truly global. And if it actually needs to be global, it needs to be placed in shared memory and accessed accordingly.

Comment: This link you shared https://ask.sagemath.org/question/63243/multiprocessing-makes-elements-of-a-custom-monoid-incompatible/ illustrates that well: the parent of the two elements is equal but not the same object, and that would have happened because operations happened in different processes with different memory. The parallel infrastructure copies what needs to be copied, but that breaks identity, and the library relies on those parents being the same object.

Comment: @joanis: Ok, then the question is essentially what needs to be added to the underlying class to avoid this issue. What does the `Permutations` class have that allows it to behave nicely under multiprocessing?

Comment: I understand the question, but this is a big contract you're asking for. I have provided general guidelines as comments, but you may have to hire a contractor, or hope someone on payroll somewhere needs the same thing solved for their employer.